# Converting existing Array into a new one

Tags: javascript, json

I have a Array that I am turning into a new one that's suitable for my work. This is the original ArrayI have:

Note: 'jayanagar', 'mallashwaram', 'kolar' are referred as city in my code.

```
var array1=[
  ["Year", "2018-8", "2017-8"],
  ["JAYANAGAR", "2018-8", 10910665], 
  ["MALLESHWARAM", "2018-8", 2018451],
  ["KOLAR", "2018-8", 2277562], 
  ["JAYANAGAR", "2017-8", 1134]
]
```

And from this I am converting it into this:

```
var array2=[
  ["Year", "Jul 2018", "Jul 2017"], 
  ["JAYANAGAR", 10910665, 1134], 
  ["MALLESHWARAM", 2018451], 
  ["KOLAR", 2277562]
]
```

What I am trying to do is

- As you can see in `arra1` I have two years, i.e `2018-8` and `2017-8`, for date `2018-8` i have all the city's  data but as for date `2017-08`  have only one city data, i.e for `jayanagar`
- So what I am trying to do is whenever there is less number of cities for previous date, I want to show as `0` for that city
- For example in `array2`, I don't have data for `malleshwaram` and `kolar` so I want to show as 0 there
- And the year user selected will give me all the names of cities, so according to that i want to loop over the other date data here, that one is `array2`
- The highest date is always going to have all the cities name

**What i have done**

```js
var input = [
  ["Year", "2018-8", "2017-8"],
  ["JAYANAGAR", "2018-8", 10910665],
  ["MALLESHWARAM", "2018-8", 2018451],
  ["KOLAR", "2018-8", 2277562],
  ["JAYANAGAR", "2017-8", 1134]
]
var e = input[0]
var a = new Date(e[1]);

a.setMonth(a.getMonth());
a = a.toUTCString();

var c = a.split(' ');
e[1] = c[2] + " " + c[3];
a = new Date(e[2]);

a.setMonth(a.getMonth());
a = a.toUTCString();
c = a.split(' ');
e[2] = c[2] + " " + c[3];

const merged = input.reduce((acc, arr) => {
  const [city, year, value] = arr;

  if (city === "Year")
    acc[city] = arr
  else {
    acc[city] = acc[city] || [city]
    acc[city].push(value)
  }

  return acc;
}, {})

const output = Object.values(merged)
console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**My expected output**

```
[
  [
    "Year",
    "Aug 2018",
    "Aug 2017"
  ],
  [
    "JAYANAGAR",
    10910665,
    1134
  ],
  [
    "MALLESHWARAM",
    2018451,
    0
  ],
  [
    "KOLAR",
    2277562,
    0
  ]
]
```

Comment: I believe July is the 7th month of the year...shouldn't it be `August 2018` etc?

Comment: There's no JSON in your code. JSON is a text format that looks like JS literals. What you have is an array of arrays.

Comment: @JackBashford because of browser dependencies it is taking it as july

Comment: It's not a JSON though!

Comment: @AbhishekGautam  fine i have edited my post

Comment: @ChrisG i have edited my post could you help me out with a answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution creates object to stores all data by same key, where key is the city, and then creates another array that formats array in wanted output.

```js
    var input = [
      ["Year", "2018-8", "2017-8"],
      ["JAYANAGAR", "2018-8", 10910665],
      ["MALLESHWARAM", "2018-8", 2018451],
      ["KOLAR", "2018-8", 2277562],
      ["JAYANAGAR", "2017-8", 1134]
    ];
    
   
  
  var cities = {};
  var years = input[0]; 

  
function formatDate(date, index){

if(index === 0){ //skip formatting, because it is not a date
  return date;
}
  dates = {
  '1' : 'Jan',
  '2' : 'Feb',
  '3' : 'Mar',
  '4' : 'Apr',
  '5' : 'May',
  '6' : 'Jun',
  '7' : 'Jul',
  '8' : 'Aug',
  '9' : 'Sep',
  '10': 'Oct',
  '11': 'Nov',
  '12': 'Dec'
  };

  let dateArr = date.split('-');

  return dates[dateArr[1]] + ' ' + dateArr[0];
 
}


years = years.map(formatDate); //run through dates array. 


  
  //store data in object items, where each key is city , and items are arrays of data
  input.forEach(function(element,index) {
    if(index !== 0){
    if( cities[element[0]] === undefined){
       cities[element[0]] = [];
    }
    
      cities[element[0]].push(element[2]); // add to city item new data
      
    }
  });
  

 var citiesData = []; 
 for (var city in cities) { //reformat the data in format [city, ...data]
    if (cities.hasOwnProperty(city)) {
      //  citiesData.push
     cities[city].unshift(city); //add city as first item in array
     if(years.length > cities[city].length){ //assuming that data should be available for each year, check the length and fill with zeroes 
     let fillsLength =  years.length -  cities[city].length;
     let fills = Array(fillsLength).fill(0, 0, fillsLength); //fill with zeros x times of missing data per each year
     cities[city] = cities[city].concat(fills); //concat array of zeros with city data
     }
     citiesData.push(cities[city]);
    }
}

citiesData.unshift(years);

console.log(citiesData);
```

Note for dates: rather than using Date and Date methods, easier would be to use the object that holds the abbreviation for each month for value, and numeric format for month for key.

Comment: here only i am stuck ,how can i check for year wise cities and putvalues as 0

Comment: @dheerajkumar,  what are the third items in each array in second level?

Comment: [city, year, value] these are the three  items in my array

Comment: @dheerajkumar, I have edited my answer with new code. You need to use help of object in this solution

Comment: @dheerajkumar, what kind of doubt? Run the snippet, and check the results.

Comment: hey sir can you help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846400/appended-new-row-is-not-behaving-like-previous-one-row