# Appended new row is not behaving like previous one (row)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a HTML table in side which i have several `td` as `input` field,my table is dynamic, when page loads i am appending the 1st row of my table and `focus` on first input field, in my case i.e `Item Name`

I have 3 input fields in my row which are `Item Name`,`Unit Qty` and `Disc%`

- When user clicks inside `ItemName` input field i am searching for itemnames from  a data which is objects inside a array to populate itemnames
- After selecting `Item NAme` i am moving my focus to next input field which is `Unit Qty` then after that focus in to next input field which is `Disc%` in between this some calculation are happening to calculate `Total Amount`
- Then after this when user is focus out from `Disc%` i am appending a new row, actually i have a function inside which i have code to append the row, so i am calling that function on focus out of `Disc%`
- After focus out of `Disc%` i want my focus should go to the `ItemName` of new row and should behave like it was behaving (Like search from data) and so on

**I have commented the lines in my code to better user understanding what is happening where**

```js
function rowappend() // this one is appending row
{
  var markup = '<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control commantd"name="itemNametd" id="itemNametd">' +
    '</td><td id="itemCodetd" class="commantd"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control commantd"name="unitQtytd" id="unitQtytd"></td>' +
    '<td id="purRatetd" class="commantd"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control commantd"name="discPercentagetd" id="discPercentagetd"></td>' +
    '<td id="discAmttd" class="commantd"></td>' +
    '<td id="gstPercentagetd" class="commantd"></td>' +
    '<td id="gstAmttd" class="commantd"></td>' +
    '<td id="totalAmttd" class="commantd"></td></tr>'
  $("table tbody").append(markup);
  $("itemNametd").next().focus();
}
rowappend()


var data = [ //data to populate Item Name search input field
  {
    "ItemName": "Butter"
  },
  {
    "ItemName": "Rice"
  },
  {
    "ItemName": "Milk"
  },
  {
    "ItemName": "Ice Cream"
  },
  {
    "ItemName": "Curd"
  }
]
var data1 = [{ // this data will be dynamic but for now to test i am using this single data
  "ItemName": "Butter",
  "ItemCode": 400564,
  "PurRate": 8,
  "DiscAmt": 6,
  "gstPercentage": 35,
  "gstAmt": 5
}]
var totalAmount = "";
var unitQuantity = "";
$(function() {
  let itemName = data.map(value => { //using autocomplete to for searching input field

    return value.ItemName;
  });
  $("#itemNametd").autocomplete({
    source: itemName
  });
});
$("#itemNametd").focusout(function() { //when user focus out from Item Name doing this

  data1.map(value => {
    $("#itemCodetd").text(value.ItemCode);
    $("#purRatetd").text(value.PurRate);
    $("#discAmttd").text(value.DiscAmt);
    $("#gstPercentahgetd").text(value.gstPercentage);
    $("#gstAmttd").text(value.gstAmt);

  });

});
$("#unitQtytd").focusout(function() { //when user focus out Unit Qty doing some calculation
  unitQuantity = $("#unitQtytd").val();
  purchaseRate = $("#purRatetd").text();
  totalAmount = (parseInt(unitQuantity) * parseInt(purchaseRate));
  $("#totalAmttd").text(totalAmount);

});
$("#discPercentagetd").focusout(function() { //here when user is focus out i am calling the fuinction which is creating new row

  rowappend()



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="container commonDivInvoice">
  <div class="row tableInvoice" id="commonDvScroll">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableInvoice">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th id="itemNameth" class="commanth">Item Name</th>
          <th id="itemCodeth" class="commanth">Item Code</th>
          <th id="unitQtyth" class="commanth">Unit Qty</th>
          <th id="purRateth" class="commanth">Pur.Rate</th>
          <th id="discPercentageth" class="commanth">Disc%</th>
          <th id="discAmtth" class="commanth">Disc Amt</th>
          <th id="gstPercentageth" class="commanth">Gst%</th>
          <th id="gstAmtth" class="commanth">Gst Amt</th>
          <th id="totalAmtth" class="commanth">Total Amount</th>


        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>


      </tbody>

    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

From my side i think i am using wrong approach to do this task

**NOTE :-** in future on each focus out i may be doing some calculations so please help me out in that way

I have provided all the information if it is not sufficient then you all can ask me in comments

**EDIT**

as per `Wils's` answer after focus out from `Disc%` new row is appending and focus is also shifting to new row's `Item Name` but issue is when new row is appending the `autocomplete` is not working in first row initially when page loads when i type m inside the input field of `Item Name` all the item name containing `m` are displayed as drop-down but for 2nd row its not showing up

```js
function rowappend() // this one is appending row
{
  var markup = $('<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control commantd"name="itemNametd" id="itemNametd">' +
    '</td><td id="itemCodetd" class="commantd"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control commantd"name="unitQtytd" id="unitQtytd"></td>' +
    '<td id="purRatetd" class="commantd"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control commantd"name="discPercentagetd" id="discPercentagetd"></td>' +
    '<td id="discAmttd" class="commantd"></td>' +
    '<td id="gstPercentagetd" class="commantd"></td>' +
    '<td id="gstAmttd" class="commantd"></td>' +
    '<td id="totalAmttd" class="commantd"></td></tr>');

  $("table tbody").append(markup);
  $("#itemNametd", markup).focus();
}
rowappend()


var data = [ //data to populate Item Name search input field
  {
    "ItemName": "Butter"
  },
  {
    "ItemName": "Rice"
  },
  {
    "ItemName": "Milk"
  },
  {
    "ItemName": "Ice Cream"
  },
  {
    "ItemName": "Curd"
  }
]
var data1 = [{ // this data will be dynamic but for now to test i am using this single data
  "ItemName": "Butter",
  "ItemCode": 400564,
  "PurRate": 8,
  "DiscAmt": 6,
  "gstPercentage": 35,
  "gstAmt": 5
}]
var totalAmount = "";
var unitQuantity = "";
$(function() {
  let itemName = data.map(value => { //using autocomplete to for searching input field

    return value.ItemName;
  });
  $("#itemNametd").autocomplete({
    source: itemName
  });
});
$("#itemNametd").focusout(function() { //when user focus out from Item Name doing this

  data1.map(value => {
    $("#itemCodetd").text(value.ItemCode);
    $("#purRatetd").text(value.PurRate);
    $("#discAmttd").text(value.DiscAmt);
    $("#gstPercentahgetd").text(value.gstPercentage);
    $("#gstAmttd").text(value.gstAmt);

  });

});
$("#unitQtytd").focusout(function() { //when user focus out Unit Qty doing some calculation
  unitQuantity = $("#unitQtytd").val();
  purchaseRate = $("#purRatetd").text();
  totalAmount = (parseInt(unitQuantity) * parseInt(purchaseRate));
  $("#totalAmttd").text(totalAmount);

});

$('body').on('focusout', '#discPercentagetd', function() {
  rowappend()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="container commonDivInvoice">
  <div class="row tableInvoice" id="commonDvScroll">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableInvoice">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th id="itemNameth" class="commanth">Item Name</th>
          <th id="itemCodeth" class="commanth">Item Code</th>
          <th id="unitQtyth" class="commanth">Unit Qty</th>
          <th id="purRateth" class="commanth">Pur.Rate</th>
          <th id="discPercentageth" class="commanth">Disc%</th>
          <th id="discAmtth" class="commanth">Disc Amt</th>
          <th id="gstPercentageth" class="commanth">Gst%</th>
          <th id="gstAmtth" class="commanth">Gst Amt</th>
          <th id="totalAmtth" class="commanth">Total Amount</th>


        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>


      </tbody>

    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone out here please help me out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with your code

The two most important are

- You use multiple elements with the same `id`. But `id`s must be unique. JavaScript/jQuery will always use the first element with the id if multiple elements have the same (CSS is different). I used `name` instead of `id` here
- You add event listeners to elements, which are not there at run-time. Only the first input-row is created, when you listen to the `focusout` events. I listen to the `focusout` event on the whole document. If you focus out of an input, the event will bubble up to the `document`, where I decide, what to do based on the event's `target` property.

I restructured your code a bit and made some improvements, but it's far from perfect.

```js
"use strict";
console.clear()


const data = [ //data to populate Item Name search input field
  {"ItemName": "Butter"},
  {"ItemName": "Rice"},
  {"ItemName": "Milk"},
  {"ItemName": "Ice Cream"},
  {"ItemName": "Curd"}
]

const data1 = {// this data will be dynamic but for now to test i am using this single data
  butter: { 
    "ItemName": "Butter",
    "ItemCode": 400564,
    "PurRate": 8,
    "DiscAmt": 6,
    "gstPercentage": 35,
    "gstAmt": 5
  },
  rice: { 
    "ItemName": "Rice",
    "ItemCode": 400565,
    "PurRate": 3,
    "DiscAmt": 2,
    "gstPercentage": 20,
    "gstAmt": 8
  },
  milk: { 
    "ItemName": "Milk",
    "ItemCode": 200569,
    "PurRate": 1,
    "DiscAmt": 1,
    "gstPercentage": 50,
    "gstAmt": 2
  },
  'ice cream': { 
    "ItemName": "Ice cream",
    "ItemCode": 800002,
    "PurRate": 16,
    "DiscAmt": 2,
    "gstPercentage": 15,
    "gstAmt": 2
  },
  curd: { 
    "ItemName": "Curd",
    "ItemCode": 100289,
    "PurRate": 9,
    "DiscAmt": 1,
    "gstPercentage": 12,
    "gstAmt": 4
  },
}

var totalAmount = "";
var unitQuantity = "";


function rowappend(tbody) {// this one is appending row{
  
  const markup = 
`<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control commantd" name="itemNametd">
  </td>
  <td name="itemCodetd" class="commantd"></td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control commantd" name="unitQtytd">
  </td>
  <td name="purRatetd" class="commantd"></td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control commantd" name="discPercentagetd">
  </td>
  <td name="discAmttd" class="commantd"></td> 
  <td name="gstPercentagetd" class="commantd"></td>
  <td name="gstAmttd" class="commantd"></td>
  <td name="totalAmttd" class="commantd"></td>
  
</tr>`
    
  $(tbody).append(markup);
  setTimeout(() => $("[name=itemNametd]", tbody).last().focus(), 100);

  const itemName = data.map(value => { //using autocomplete to for searching input field
    return value.ItemName;
  });
  $("[name=itemNametd]", tbody).last().autocomplete({
    source: itemName
  });
}
rowappend($('tbody', '#tableInvoice'))


function getValues(row) {
  const search = ($('[name=itemNametd]', row).val()).toString()
  const value = data1[search.toLowerCase()];
  if (value) {
    $(row).find("[name=itemCodetd]").text(value.ItemCode);
    $(row).find("[name=purRatetd]").text(value.PurRate);
    $(row).find("[name=discAmttd]").text(value.DiscAmt);
    $(row).find("[name=gstPercentahgetd]").text(value.gstPercentage);
    $(row).find("[name=gstAmttd]").text(value.gstAmt);
  }
}



function calc(row) {
  const unitQuantity = $(row).find("[name=unitQtytd]").val();
  const purchaseRate = $(row).find("[name=purRatetd]").text();
  const totalAmount = (parseInt(unitQuantity) * parseInt(purchaseRate));
  
  $(row).find("[name=totalAmttd]").text(totalAmount);
  
}

$(document).on('focusout', (e) => {
  const row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
  if (e.target.matches('[name=discPercentagetd]')) {
    if ($(row).parent().find('tr').length - $(row).index() === 1) { // only last row
        rowappend(e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement)
    }
  }
  
  if (e.target.matches('[name=unitQtytd]')) {
    calc(e.target.parentElement.parentElement)
  }

  if (e.target.matches("[name=itemNametd]")) {
    getValues(e.target.parentElement.parentElement)
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container commonDivInvoice">
  <div class="row tableInvoice" id="commonDvScroll">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableInvoice">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th id="itemNameth" class="commanth">Item Name</th>
          <th id="itemCodeth" class="commanth">Item Code</th>
          <th id="unitQtyth" class="commanth">Unit Qty</th>
          <th id="purRateth" class="commanth">Pur.Rate</th>
          <th id="discPercentageth" class="commanth">Disc%</th>
          <th id="discAmtth" class="commanth">Disc Amt</th>
          <th id="gstPercentageth" class="commanth">Gst%</th>
          <th id="gstAmtth" class="commanth">Gst Amt</th>
          <th id="totalAmtth" class="commanth">Total Amount</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>

    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @dheerajkumar This is a new question and you should post it as a new question. But first you should try for yourself. And if you think your question is answered, please accept the answer

Comment: i have accepted your answer sir,but you can make some edit than it would be helpful

Comment: @dheerajkumar I made plenty of improvements to your code. It's now your turn to try and learn

Comment: hey sir I have been following your code structure, I have done many things, as here the table is populated when page is loaded and `itemName` data is coming from JSON so I have a drop-down on click I am creating table row, so when I selects first option there data comes as autocomplete in `ItemName` field but when I change it to option 2 and loads other data it  still takes  first data only which is for option one, if you get little bit of time then please help me out and have a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/draj8126/hwvne90d/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the element selector target in this case markup.
You have to add the listener again after you create a new DOM element.

```js
function rowappend() // this one is appending row
{
  var markup = $('<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control commantd"name="itemNametd" id="itemNametd">' +
    '</td><td id="itemCodetd" class="commantd"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control commantd"name="unitQtytd" id="unitQtytd"></td>' +
    '<td id="purRatetd" class="commantd"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control commantd"name="discPercentagetd" id="discPercentagetd"></td>' +
    '<td id="discAmttd" class="commantd"></td>' +
    '<td id="gstPercentagetd" class="commantd"></td>' +
    '<td id="gstAmttd" class="commantd"></td>' +
    '<td id="totalAmttd" class="commantd"></td></tr>');
    
  $("table tbody").append(markup);
  $("#itemNametd",markup).focus();
}
rowappend()


var data = [ //data to populate Item Name search input field
  {
    "ItemName": "Butter"
  },
  {
    "ItemName": "Rice"
  },
  {
    "ItemName": "Milk"
  },
  {
    "ItemName": "Ice Cream"
  },
  {
    "ItemName": "Curd"
  }
]
var data1 = [{ // this data will be dynamic but for now to test i am using this single data
  "ItemName": "Butter",
  "ItemCode": 400564,
  "PurRate": 8,
  "DiscAmt": 6,
  "gstPercentage": 35,
  "gstAmt": 5
}]
var totalAmount = "";
var unitQuantity = "";
$(function() {
  let itemName = data.map(value => { //using autocomplete to for searching input field

    return value.ItemName;
  });
  $("#itemNametd").autocomplete({
    source: itemName
  });
});
$("#itemNametd").focusout(function() { //when user focus out from Item Name doing this

  data1.map(value => {
    $("#itemCodetd").text(value.ItemCode);
    $("#purRatetd").text(value.PurRate);
    $("#discAmttd").text(value.DiscAmt);
    $("#gstPercentahgetd").text(value.gstPercentage);
    $("#gstAmttd").text(value.gstAmt);

  });

});
$("#unitQtytd").focusout(function() { //when user focus out Unit Qty doing some calculation
  unitQuantity = $("#unitQtytd").val();
  purchaseRate = $("#purRatetd").text();
  totalAmount = (parseInt(unitQuantity) * parseInt(purchaseRate));
  $("#totalAmttd").text(totalAmount);

});

    $('body').on('focusout','#discPercentagetd', function(){
      rowappend()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="container commonDivInvoice">
  <div class="row tableInvoice" id="commonDvScroll">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableInvoice">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th id="itemNameth" class="commanth">Item Name</th>
          <th id="itemCodeth" class="commanth">Item Code</th>
          <th id="unitQtyth" class="commanth">Unit Qty</th>
          <th id="purRateth" class="commanth">Pur.Rate</th>
          <th id="discPercentageth" class="commanth">Disc%</th>
          <th id="discAmtth" class="commanth">Disc Amt</th>
          <th id="gstPercentageth" class="commanth">Gst%</th>
          <th id="gstAmtth" class="commanth">Gst Amt</th>
          <th id="totalAmtth" class="commanth">Total Amount</th>


        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>


      </tbody>

    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey but when i am typing something inside `Item Name` autocomplete is not working for new row

Comment: because you cannot use id twice... you have to use class or input field array.

Comment: that's the main issue  where i am stuck now when 2nd row is appended  after focus out  from `Disc%` 3rd row is not appending

Comment: try my snippet, I fixed that for you.

Comment: you should bind the listener to body instead of an element, so your newly created DOM object can have the action.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should assign a variable to the table:

document. getElementById('I'd of table body');

To create the record build it as elements:

document.createElement('tr'),
document.createElement('td');
Append to to tr.
repeat as necessary...

Then append the new record element to the table body.
Each element may be added to, such as adding attributes like class or events.

For this final record event add an on blur handler. 
document.addEventHandler('blur', function callback);

Comment: Ddheeraj, sure I'd love to help and wish I saw this earlier. Let me know if you still need assistance.

Comment: As i have written all the things in my post, i am trying to append new row when last column of first row is focus out, and in each input field focus out i am calculating some values, some calculations are going one, so i want help in form of some code